Why extension method that takes object as parameter cannot work on iff because late binding prohibit it?
Iff is a function whose return value is object right
Look at this code
    Dim obj1 = 5
    Dim str1 = obj1.ToCultureInvariantString
    Dim obj2 As Object = "hi"
    Dim str2 = obj1.ToCultureInvariantString
    Dim str3 = iff(True, obj1, obj2).ToCultureInvariantString

All lines work except the last one. The result of iff is an object of type Object. So why didn't it work.
The extension is defined like this
<Extension()>
Public Function ToCultureInvariantString(obj As Object) As String
    If TypeOf obj Is IFormattable Then
        Return CType(obj, IFormattable).ToString(Nothing, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Else
        Return obj.ToString()
    End If
End Function

Obviously the function ToCultureInvariantString accepts object, but somehow I can't pass an Object instant to that function.
Because it violate late binding?
Weird.
Why?
Another samples where it doesn't work
    Dim ar2 = ar.ConvertAll(Function(x) x.ToCultureInvariantString)

produces late binding error too
 Function(x) If(x.Value Is Nothing, "", x.Value.ToString) also doesn't work.

I expect my extension function tocultureinvariant string should work on instance of Object class.
I got option strict doesn't allow late binding error

Are you actually talking about the IIf function or is this iff some invention of your own?

You cannot use extension methods for System.Object in VB.NET, this is a known limitation.

the only way we could prevent extension methods from completely
breaking existing late bound code was to prevent them from being used
on anything typed as object

So you get this compiler error (with Option Strict On):

BC30574   Option Strict On disallows late binding

With Option Strict Off you get the runtime error MissingMemberException.
However, using extension methods for System.Object are almost never appropriate anyway.
